# sqldataadapter inserting duplicate rows in destination table

Tags: vb.net, dataset, sqldataadapter

I am using .NET and using sqldataadapter to get data from one data source and updating another data source. But problem is every time it is inserting duplicate rows in destination table.

```
   Dim sqlconl As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conl) --LOCAL SQL CONNECTION
   Dim sqlconr As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conr) --REMOTE SQL CONNECTION
   Dim dsl As New DataSet()  --DSL AS DATASET
   Dim dal As New SqlDataAdapter()  --DAL AS SQLDATAADAPTER
```

---

```
    dal.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from TxnDependents where Personalized='1'", sqlconl)
    dal.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
    dal.Fill(dsl, "TxnDependents")`
    Dim dar1 As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from TxnDependents", sqlconr)
    Dim U1 As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dar1)
    dar1.Update(dsl, "TxnDependents")
    dsl.Dispose()
    dal.Dispose()
```

Comment: Is this all the code that creates the problem? Is there some code between the local loading of the dataset and the update on the remote connection? AFAIK you shouldn't get any kind of update with this code because all rows are in the unchanged row state.

Comment: No , it's all I have. It's working but every time it inserting old data (which already inserted earlier) with new data.

Comment: My problem is I am unable to set any condition like dal.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from TxnDependents where Personalized='1' and URN not in (Select URN from txndependent,sqlconr)", sqlconl)

Comment: Use a temporary table on the remote to load the local data. (That you should TRUNCATE before every new load) Then you can write your query that updates only the new records using the same remote connection

Answer (score 1):

Of course; the first query makes no effort not to select rows that are already in the destination table so they will be added again

Imagine:

```
Source Table      Dest Table
Id, Name          Id, Name
1, Matthew        
2, Mark
3, Luke
```

Then you select all, and update (insert) so you have:

```
Source Table      Dest Table
Id, Name          Id, Name
1, Matthew        1, Matthew
2, Mark           2, Mark
3, Luke           3, Luke
```

Then you add some more rows to the source table:

```
Source Table      Dest Table
Id, Name          Id, Name
1, Matthew        1, Matthew
2, Mark           2, Mark
3, Luke           3, Luke
4, John
```

Then you select all and insert into the destination table again:

```
Source Table      Dest Table
Id, Name          Id, Name
1, Matthew        1, Matthew
2, Mark           2, Mark
3, Luke           3, Luke
4, John           1, Matthew
                  2, Mark
                  3, Luke
                  4, John
```

Every time you do this, you'll cause more and more duplicates

Perhaps consider something like:

```
SELECT MAX(id) as maxid FROM destination --retrieve this into C#
SELECT * FROM source WHERE id > @maxid   --pass the max id into this query that pulls the source data
```

If your IDs are guids or don't sort nicely, use something else like a CreatedDate column (any row in the source whose createddate is > the max createddate in the dest, assuming the dest date is copied, and not calculated as the date it truly was inserted, which could cause some records to go missing).

If you don't have anything else you're going to have to do something tedious like selecting all the IDs from the dest table, and not selecting those IDs from the source table. It would be better, really, to have a column that controls/tracks whether the data has been transferred, or a column that you can select (like a created date or numerical sequence) on to prevent bringing down data you already transferred

Comment: Yes that would happen if the RowState in all the source rows will be marked with the DataRowState.Added, but this doesn't seem to be the case. The final Update will never add rows (or update or delete) to the destination table if they have the RowStete = DateRowState.Unchanged as they are after the call to Fill. The problem is not as presented by the OP

Comment: I think you didn't notice the OP's `AcceptChangesDuringFill = False` line of code... All the rows added during fill have a DataRowState of Added

Comment: Awh I see it now, simply blanked out on that!

Comment: So.. is it reason that duplicate data entering in destination table?   Is Acceptchangesduringfill= true will solve the issue??

Comment: @DIPANKAR no; please read my answer again and let me know what part of it you get to before you don't understand what is going on

Comment: @CAIUS The part AcceptChangesDuringFill=False made me confused. Can you tell me if DataTable will give me some advantages to select only the new data from filled DataAdapter from data source?

Comment: No. The datatable isn't some intelligent unique collection of rows, it's just a dumb container of data. If it helps, then think of this like files: you have a folder with 3 files, and you select all and copy and paste to a destination folder. Then you add one new file into the source folder, then you select all 4 files again, copy all and paste into the destination folder. Now you have 7 files in the destination: two copies of files 1, 2 and 3 and one copy of file 4. You never make any effort to only select the new file for copy, you just blindly select all each time. It causes duplication

Comment: @Caius Now I got it. Now I added a column named "srv_ststus" and it's default value is '0'. I set an update query "update table set srv_status='0' " when upload will be completed. But can you guide me to something like that? Row 1 uploaded, srv_status set to '1'. row 2 upload , srv_status set to '1'. I want to update srv_status immediately if upload successful, not @ the end.

Comment: Seems to me you should do more like have that column be a batch number; first select the max batch number, then add 1, then update all rows with batch number = 0 to be batch number = the new batch number, then select all rows with the new batch number; they are the ones not uploaded. If any fail you can set their number to eg -1 and decide what to do later